# Prove that $\frac{x^2}{x^2+2y}+\frac{y^2}{y^2+2z}+\frac{z^2}{z^2+2x} \ge 1$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, holder-inequality

> Prove that
> $$\frac{x^2}{x^2+2y}+\frac{y^2}{y^2+2z}+\frac{z^2}{z^2+2x} \ge 1$$
> with $xy+yz+zx=3$ and $x,y,z >0$.

If I use Cauchy-Schwarz then $\frac{x^2}{x^2+2y}+\frac{y^2}{y^2+2z}+\frac{z^2}{z^2+2x} \ge \frac{(x+y+z)^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2+2(x+y+z)}\le 1$

How can I solve that?

Comment: Please include the source of you question.

Comment: Not true. Take $x=0$, $y = -1$ and $z = -3$.

Comment: Oh. I'm sorry for miss the condition x, y, z >0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Cauchy-Schwarz in the form
$$
\frac{x^2}{x^2+2y}+\frac{y^2}{y^2+2z}+\frac{z^2}{z^2+2x}\\=
\frac{x^3}{x^3+2xy}+\frac{y^3}{y^3+2yz}+\frac{z^3}{z^3+2xz} \\
\geq \dfrac{\left (\sqrt{x^3}+\sqrt{y^3}+\sqrt{z^3}\right )^2}{x^3+y^3+z^3+2(xy+yz+zx)} \\
= \dfrac{\left (\sqrt{x^3}+\sqrt{y^3}+\sqrt{z^3}\right )^2}{x^3+y^3+z^3+6}
$$
So it is enough to prove
$\left (\sqrt{x^3}+\sqrt{y^3}+\sqrt{z^3}\right )^2\geq x^3+y^3+z^3+6\Leftrightarrow \sqrt{x^3y^3}+\sqrt{y^3z^3}+\sqrt{z^3x^3}\geq 3$.

This can be shown using  Hölder's inequality:
$\left ( \sqrt{x^3y^3}+\sqrt{y^3z^3}+\sqrt{z^3x^3}\right )\left ( \sqrt{x^3y^3}+\sqrt{y^3z^3}+\sqrt{z^3x^3}\right )(1+1+1)\geq (xy+yz+zx)^3=27$ which is exactly $\sqrt{x^3y^3}+\sqrt{y^3z^3}+\sqrt{z^3x^3}\geq 3$.

Comment: Thank you so much!